# How can I get the path of directory in which the command is running?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, root

Suppose there is a bash file named "`uploadme`" in the `/usr/bin` folder.

*I am using that file as a command*, and passing the **file names** as a **command line argument**, in any subdirectory of my home directory.

Suppose I am in the directory directory`/home/John/documents/`. In that directory, there is only one file that exists, named "Hello.txt". I will use the command as:

```
uploadme Hello.txt
```

So, the bash file will get one argument as "Hello.txt", but **I want the full path of the file without mentioning it in the argument.**

How can we do that?

Comment: What do you mean that you want the full path? Do you want to pass the full path to the command or do you want to print the full path after you run the command?

Answer (score 5):

The tool `realpath` does that:

```
echo $(realpath "$1")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `readlink -f`:

```
readlink -f "$1"
```

Comment: That's strange. [`man 1 realpath`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/realpath.1.html) says resolving symlinks *is* the default behaviour.

Comment: oh that is true.... strange, I thought I have checked that, maybe it was before my coffee^^

Answer (score 2):

There is an environment variable named `PWD` that holds the name of the current/working directory. Also, the command `pwd` prints the current directory.

So you can get the full path to the passed argument in your script with `$PWD/$1`.

Comment: What if you use an absolute path as argument? `uploadme /path/to/file` will then give you `/home/John/documents//path/to/file`.

Comment: @pLumo, IMO, this answer the question.  In the OP we can see the following condition: *Suppose I am in `/home/John/documents/` directory.*... In addition we can use also the envvar `$PWD` instead capturing the output of `pwd` by a command substitution `$()` .

Comment: I would disagree. I guess, "*suppose i am in ...*" is just an example and can be different. But yes, for **that** example, the answer would be valid, but still `readlink` or `realpath` are more general and thus better options.

Comment: Hey @pa4080, for me `$PWD` is working fine, as I just need the absolute path of that file.

Comment: @pa4080 you are right, I forgot about the variable, thanks! I updated the answer to use the env var instead of command subsitution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the path to the command, rather than to the file argument, you can use the `which` command. If, inside the scripted command, you want to know where the command is (rather than the current working directory or the full path to a parameter file), you can look at `which $0` (for scripts) or `argv[0]` (for compiled programs).